# Help retag the [list] tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

There are currently 249 questions tagged with both [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [list](/questions/tagged/list). Yet, if you read the [list](/questions/tagged/list) wiki it says to use the tag [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists) when asking questions about unordered/ordered lists.

> **Do not** use this tag for unordered/ordered lists in HTML, use [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists)
> instead.

So, I'm calling on the Community to not only retag, but to improve questions tagged [with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+list) [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [list](/questions/tagged/list). That way, all those questions are properly tagged with [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists).

## [Here's the link.  Go get 'em!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+list)

Remember to start from the last page so you're not overlapping with other editors.

---

### We are done!

We've managed to retagged all the questions that should of been tagged [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists). The remaining 15 questions (as of Mon, Jun 4, 2012) seem to be appropriate. Thanks for everyone who helped retagged!

---

### Acceptable Questions

The following questions are acceptable and **should not** be retagged.

1. [Generate HTML Table from Python 2-Dimensional List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165587/generate-html-table-from-python-2-dimensional-list)

Comment: You said it, but let me reiterate: **do not *just* retag, improve other things that need improving** (other bad tagging, spelling, signatures, vague titles, bad formatting, etc.).

Comment: I did a few, but I'm not sure they were worthwhile.  Lots of really low-quality questions with these tags.  Don't be afraid to downvote while you're at this.

Comment: "Remember to start from the last page so you're not overlapping with other editors." -- If we all do that, we *will* be overlapping.

Comment: Going through some of these I have noticed several also misusing [select] with [html], may want to consider a retag-request of those too

Comment: @fbfcn Good catch. Sadly though, there seems to be other tags such as [tag:css] and [tag:jquery] that might need to be cleaned up also.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is done, it appears that the remaining questions (19 remaining at this point) are valid [list](/questions/tagged/list) questions.

Comment: Hey, can we get a moderator here to tag this as [tag:status-completed]?